# What can cause output voltage of DC-DC Switching regulator(AP6502) to drop when load is applied?

Tags: buck, switching-regulator

I am using a DC - DC switching regulator to provide a LOAD with regulated 5V. I have followed the reference ckt provided in the datasheet but when I upload a load greater than 1A the output voltage drops from 5V to 1.1V. And the feedback voltage drops from 0.927V to 0.221V. Below is the CKT.

When I disconnect the LOAD the voltage becomes stable and I get 5V. Please tell me where I am making the mistake.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the input voltage? And is it stable when you increase the load (for example, is your lab supply current limiting?).

Comment: My Input Voltage is 12V. Yes The input voltage remains stable when I increase the load.And the Source of the Input is a Bike battery which can supply ~12V,10A

Comment: Do you have a PCB made with good layout and the thermal pad connected? A photo and/or image of the layout would be helpful.

Comment: Inductor part no. used is NR6045T100M

Comment: Do you have a link to the 10uH inductor? What sort of layout technique have you used?

Comment: Inductor part no. used is NR6045T100M

Comment: Yes I have the layout but how do I add the image here . I am not finding the tab to add an image. Thanks Spehro

Comment: Yup, the inductor is fine!

Comment: How close is the 22uF to pin 2 of the chip and ground plane?

Comment: Same tab as when you uploaded the cct.

Comment: Then Where am I going wrong ? why is the o/p voltage drop when a LOAD is applied . Yes the Thermal pad is connected

Comment: Need to see a layout - if you can post one anywhere, I'll copy n paste - leave a comment with @andy at the beginning and it'll inform me.

Comment: @andy. I have attached the Layout , Is that visible to you?

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see C2 at all. It should be very close to the chip.

Answer (score 2):

The ground system you are using is a train wreck! - I've highlighted in pink where it is on the top side of the board: -

[image]

And on the bottom side: -

[image]

Maybe it's my eyesight but I can't see the all-important C2 (power decoupler to the chip) either.

You really need very thick tracks/ground plane/sensible star-pointing of grounds for this to work as you might expect it to. For a start the return path of C5 should be back to the ground on the chip - there are rather large pulses of current flowing down those tracks and they should be as short as possible. Instead you appear to have the bottom end of C5 snaking around some very sensitive areas of the feedback components.

You've deleted the circuit so I can't tell you which cct references.

Comment: Ha spehro said the same about C2. Now that means it has to be missing - vital as your vital organs!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

@andy, @Spehro, Thanks for your support.

Above is the attached bottom layer file where the C2 is marked in the red which comes in the bottom and close to PIN 2. And my AP6502 IC is on TOP Layer.

Comment: Not having an ident name for C2?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Andy, @Spehro Attached is the GND observed on the oscilloscope, which shows some noise when I connect the External LOAD. C5(47uF) which is a output cap is away from the IC, Is that the reason for causing the Noise on GND palne If yes how do I resolve this.?

The input 12V, Output 5v which drops to 0.8v ~ 0.9V looks stable when I connect the LOAD

Give me solution to test the setup before going for a RE-SPIN of the board.

Thanks,
Automate

Comment: You mention ground plane. You don't have one according to the pictures. You have a highly inductive track snaking around that tries to be ground. Maybe the gp is on a 3rd layer?

Comment: @Andy, The board is only a 2 layered there is no 3rd layer.Should I take the GND as star network(meaning from a single point to all). Placing the C5 cap close to VOUT will that help in reducing the noise.

Comment: You should try this technique then post back with what you plan but this time lets have all the component IDs listed and a full circuit of the PCB!

Comment: @Andy, So  should  i go ahead with the new PCB layout and post the layout design for the review here with the component list and ckt? Anything can I try before going for a new layout design with the current board like cutting the traces and taking a single GND plane as reference and hardwire the CKT then test. What do You recommend?

Comment: Yes maybe you can try soldering bare copper wire back from the gnd connection of C5 directly to underneath the chip and lose the gnd connection to sensitive components. There are a few things to try and it costs nothing to do these virtually.